# Reading SAS table, showing up � in value. ENCODING

Tags: encoding, sas

Currently reading an existing table in SAS. When reading the table, I noticed some values aren't encoded correctly.

For example, Bioparc de la Gasp�.
I saved this table in a csv file to look closely on this matter. When I open this file in notepad++, I notice that the value shows up Bioparc de la GaspxC3. And referencing xC3 on https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html, it shows as the character "Ã"

I have tried changing the encoding to utf-8 but it doesn't seem to change this issue.

My expected output is Bioparc de la GaspÃ.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to check what encoding your SAS session is using.  Check the value of the system option ENCODING.  You need check what encoding the existing SAS dataset is using for example by using PROC CONTENTS.  Writing the value to a CSV from the SAS session that is not reading the value properly to begin with it is probably not going to add much value.  If you want to see what characters are in a string just print it using the $HEX format, not need to try to transfer it to Notepad.

Comment: I'd guess [Bioparc de la Gaspésie](https://bioparc.ca/en/contact-us/)?

Comment: é is C3A9 - that's probably what it is.  You looked up 0xC3 in Windows 1252 (which is single-byte), that's different.